# Do two unitary operators that commute have same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I have this example on a textbook but it does not seem to be right.

---

Example:
If A,B are unitary operators and AB=BA,prove that A and B have same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not necessarily have the same eigenvalues. Consider the operators $I$ and $-I$, which definitely commute, and are both self-adjoint and square to $I$. However, the eigenvalues of $I$ are just $1$, whereas the eigenvalues of $-I$ are just $-1$. You might be looking for the statement that commuting diagonalizable operators are simultaneously diagonalizable; that is, that they have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to prove that they have same eigenvalues because i didn't thought it would be a mistake in textbook.